# tailwind.cssでno route(base,utilite,component)となってレイアウトが反映されません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwindcss

railsでtailwind.cssを使っているのですがcssが反映されずターミナルのコンソールログで

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/tailwindcss/components"):
  
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/tailwindcss/utilities"):
  

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/tailwindcss/base"):
```

ルーティングエラーとなっており、components, utilities,baseはstylesheets/application.tailwind.cssに以下のようにimportしました。

```
/*
 * Your custom CSS goes here but before adding a lot of CSS check this out:
 *   https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components
*/
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

tailwind.cssファイルにインポートしたはずなのに適用できてないのはと思いapplication.html.erbも以下のように変更したのに全然効果がありません

application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.tailwind.css", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

ちなみにtailwind関連のファイルの内容としては

tailwind.config.js

```
  module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/views/**/*.html.erb',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/assets/stylesheets/**/*.css',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js'
  ]
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
      require('postcss-import'),
      require('tailwindcss'),
      require('autoprefixer'),
    ]
  }
```

どなたかこちらのエラーに関して分かる方がいましたらコメント頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 次回以降、ソースコードを貼る際は、[Markdown](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) を使用してください。